# CSS changing border color of block level element on hover for just the text

Tags: css, hover, border, html

Consider the following:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="somelink" class="navlink"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="somelink" class="navlink"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="somelink" class="navlink"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the stylesheet behind this (simplified):

```
li {width: 150px;}
a {display:block; text-decoration:none;}
a.navlink span {border-bottom: 1px solid red;}
a.navlink:hover {border-color: magenta;}
```

As you will see the link which surrounds the text has been expanded to cover the whole box. However only the actual text itself has a border underneath it, to prevent the border appearing across the whole box. What I am trying to achieve is that when you hover over anywhere inside the a (so the whole box), the border color changes.

I can get it so that the border color changes if you just hover over the text, and if I change the border-color line above to something like background-color: magenta; it also works. However I think because the border has been assigned to the span, and not the navlink class, I don't think the hover is working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if its just me but your question is hard to understand. Try again and just make it simple. I would like the border around the whole `<ul>` to change color. Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean like this. So when you hover over any of the `<a>` it will change the border on the `<span>` thats inside `<a>`. Check it out.

### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="navlink"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="navlink"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="navlink"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

```
li {
    width: 150px;
}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navlink span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.navlink:hover > span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7NKBg/2/)

---

Your version fixed:

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7NKBg/3/)

Comment: That was exactly what I was after, and it works beautifully! Many thanks, and apologies about the confusion in the question.

Comment: @Whitenoise Glad I could help, the confusion may have just been caused by my brain :P

Comment: Don't suppose you would know how to get .navlink:hover > span to work with IE6 since it doesn't support child selectors?

Answer (score 0):

```
li {width: 150px;}
a {display:block; text-decoration:none;}
a.navlink span {border-bottom: 1px solid red;}
a.navlink span:hover {border: 1px solid magenta;}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Nt9k/1/)

Change your `a.navlink:hover {border-color: magenta;}` to `a.navlink span:hover {border: 1px solid magenta;}`

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7NKBg/1/)**

**css**

```
li {
    width: 150px;
}
a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.navlink span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
a.navlink span:hover {
    border-color: magenta;

}
```